# Proper way to modify variables from an XML layout in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, variables, layout

I am currently trying to learn Android programming, and have now come across my first problem:

What is the proper/preferred (or are there any other ways) to use an XML layout with variables as strings?

For example, I have a text field in one Activity/layout, then a button forwards to another Avctivity with a new layout.  But I want to display the string the user entered in the previous screen to modify or replace the strings called from my xml template.

One way to do this is to:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_string); 
myTextView.setText("new_string");
```

Esentially the strings in this Activity's XML template depends on the actions in the previous Activity. Is this the best way to do this, or is there a better way to handle cases like this, without the need to explicitly redefine all the strings I wish to use?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the best way to do this

It is the only way "to do this". By definition, you do not know what the user will type in, until the user types it in. By that point in time, your app is compiled, distributed, and running. Hence, you have to set the text in the `TextView` at runtime, from Java.

> or is there a better way to handle cases like this, without the need to explicitly redefine all the strings I wish to use?

Well, there's no point in having an `android:text` attribute on the `<TextView>` elements in your layout, if you are filling those in at runtime. Hence, you will not "redefine all the strings", for any conventional definition of "redefine".